# Drag and Drop images from div to div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create a game, however I am having some trouble when it comes to users dragging and dropping images that are embedded inside divs. I am currently using this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop2) to do this, however as I'm sure you can guess, it's not working. I have attached my [github](https://github.com/frankvp11/CandyCrush2.0/tree/main/website) repo below for testing purposes, currently you can ignore the python files as they are not relevant to this problem. If you find out how you can make this work, feel free to let me know, and if you need more information i'd be happy to provide it.

So basically, I have a div which contains the entire game called container. Within this div, there are a bunch of divs which contain the columns. Then inside these divs there are divs, which contain images inside of them. I am trying to move the div's images from within the container div, ie move from one row to the next, or one column to the next. However, the "dropping" part doesn't seem to be working. It for some reason doesn't update it, even though I practically copy/pasted code from the W3 schools site.

Comment: Is [this the sort of thing](https://pastebin.com/CgPzEkFV) you were trying to do?

Comment: Yes and no. The fact that the dragging works now is great, however I wanted to be able to swap the images, kind of like a puzzle. The end goal is that I move the image to the right/left/up/down and it swaps with them. It's great that they are able to move into that specific box now, however I would like to maintain the positioning of the divs while that is being done.

Comment: Ideally it would look something along the lines of this, but then in Javascript of course. This recording was taken in python's pygame of a similar project that my friend did: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n97VLJwksOeoBivL4wxL2N2FYvkmts9r/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet swaps the dragged image from the source container with the image from the target container.

The snippet also provides the option for a move only (i.e. the source container is inserted before the target container).

Using CSS Grid to create the grid allows for a swap or a move without changing the grid setup.

```
/* Set the following CSS variables in JavaScript to allow for any grid size */
:root {
    --rows: 1;
    --cols: 1;
    --cell-size: 90px;
}

#grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), var(--cell-size));
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), var(--cell-size));
}
```

Code snippet

```js
const candy_codes = {
  1: '/candies/Blue.png',
  2: '/candies/Green.png',
  3: '/candies/Orange.png',
  4: '/candies/Purple.png',
  5: '/candies/Red.png',
  6: '/candies/Yellow.png',
  7: '/candies/BlueWrapped.png',
  8: '/candies/GreenWrapped.png',
  9: '/candies/OrangeWrapped.png',
  10: '/candies/PurpleWrapped.png',
  11: '/candies/RedWrapped.png',
  12: '/candies/YellowWrapped.png'
};

const numOfRows = 12;
const numOfCols = 9;

let grid;
let gridContainerElem;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
  gridContainerElem = document.getElementById("grid-container");

  // https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript
  let root = document.documentElement;
  root.style.setProperty('--rows', numOfRows);
  root.style.setProperty('--cols', numOfCols);

  createGridArray();
  createImageGrid();
  printGridArray();

  initEvents();
}

function initEvents() {
  const cloneContainerEl = document.querySelector("#clone-container");
  cloneContainerEl.addEventListener("drop", dropClone);
  cloneContainerEl.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
}

// ------------------------------------------------------
//  Grid setup

function createGridArray() {
  grid = new Array(numOfRows);
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    grid[i] = new Array(numOfCols);
  }
}

function createImageGrid() {
  const maxNumOfCandyCodes = Object.keys(candy_codes).length;

  let uniqueIdIndex = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
    // Generate image elements within row container
    for (let j = 0; j < numOfCols; j++) {
      image_num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumOfCandyCodes) + 1);
      const src = candy_codes[image_num];
      const uniqueId = "img" + uniqueIdIndex++;
      const tdiv = addImage(src, uniqueId);
      gridContainerElem.appendChild(tdiv);
      grid[i][j] = uniqueId;
    }
  }
}

function addImage(src, id) {
  // Create a container for the image element
  const tdiv = document.createElement("div");
  tdiv.className = "image-container";
  tdiv.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
  tdiv.addEventListener("drop", dropSwapOrMove);

  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.className = "color-image";
  img.src = src;
  img.id = id;
  img.setAttribute("data-id", id);
  img.draggable = true;
  img.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstart);

  // Set the 'alt' attribute using the 'src' file name
  // and the 'id' parameter.
  let filename = src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); // Remove path
  filename = filename.split(".")[0]; // Remove extension
  const splitWordsArr = filename.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
  const combinedWords = splitWordsArr.join(" ").toLowerCase();
  img.setAttribute("alt", `${combinedWords} ${id}`);

  // For debugging purposes
  tdiv.setAttribute("data-color", splitWordsArr[0].toLowerCase());

  // Append image element to a div container
  tdiv.appendChild(img);

  return tdiv;
}

function printGridArray() {
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    let ranText = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
      ranText += grid[i][j];
      ranText += " ";
    }
    console.log(ranText);
  }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------
//  Drag and drop

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragstart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("sourceId", ev.target.getAttribute("data-id"));
}

function dropSwapOrMove(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const radioButtonGroup = document.getElementsByName("drop-type");
  const checkedRadio = Array.from(radioButtonGroup)
    .find((radio) => radio.checked);
  //console.log("Drop type " + checkedRadio.id);

  // Get source image ID set in the 'dragstart()' event handler
  const sourceId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("sourceId");
  const sourceImageElem = document.querySelector(`[data-id= "${sourceId}"]`);
  const sourceContainerElem = sourceImageElem.closest(".image-container");
  const sourceColor = sourceContainerElem.getAttribute("data-color");

  const targetContainerElem = ev.currentTarget;
  const targetImageElem = targetContainerElem.querySelector("img");
  const targetId = targetImageElem.getAttribute("data-id");
  const targetColor = targetContainerElem.getAttribute("data-color");

  if (checkedRadio.id === "move") {
    gridContainerElem.insertBefore(sourceContainerElem, targetContainerElem.nextSibling);

    console.log(`MOVE ${sourceId} (source) before ${targetId} (target)`);
    return;
  }

  // Swap images

  // Append the target image element first to the source
  // since 'sourceImageElem.closest(".image-container")'
  // returns the image container of the source image
  // BEFORE it's moved to the target image container.
  sourceContainerElem.appendChild(targetImageElem);
  sourceContainerElem.setAttribute("data-color", targetColor);

  // 'ev.currentTarget' represents the image container
  // (i.e. div.image-container)
  targetContainerElem.appendChild(sourceImageElem);
  targetContainerElem.setAttribute("data-color", sourceColor);

  console.log(`SWAP ${sourceId} (source) with ${targetId} (target)`);
}

function dropClone(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const sourceId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("sourceId");
  const clone = document.querySelector(`[data-id= "${sourceId}"]`).cloneNode(true);
  ev.target.innerHTML = "";
  ev.target.appendChild(clone);
  console.log("Dropped clone " + sourceId);
}
```

```css
/* Set the following CSS variables in JavaScript */

:root {
  --rows: 1;
  --cols: 1;
  --cell-size: 90px;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), var(--cell-size));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), var(--cell-size));
}

#clone-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

img.color-image {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

div.image-container {
  display: grid;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

img.color-image {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

div.image-container[data-color=red] {
  background-color: red;
}

div.image-container[data-color=orange] {
  background-color: orange;
}

div.image-container[data-color=yellow] {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000;
}

div.image-container[data-color=blue] {
  background-color: blue;
}

div.image-container[data-color=green] {
  background-color: green;
}

div.image-container[data-color=purple] {
  background-color: purple;
}

#move-type-control {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

#move-type-control label {
  display: flex;
}

#move-type-control label span {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="move-type-control">
  <label for="swap">
        <input type="radio" id="swap" name="drop-type" value="JavaScript" checked>
        <span>Swap</span>
    </label>
  <label for="move">
        <input type="radio" id="move" name="drop-type" value="JavaScript">
        <span>Move</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="grid-container"></div>
<div><span>Drag-n-drop clone container</span></div>
<div id="clone-container"></div>
```

Comment: This is "almost" perfect. The swapping and moving part is perfect in the web browser. However when I copy/paste the code locally it doesn't render the images. I'm going to try and debug this and come back with a new comment

Comment: I was dumb -> forgot to init(). Thank you so much!

Comment: @FrankvanPaassen Glad that worked. There are a lot of extra bits in the code snippet that I added as visual cues in place of actual images to enable the code to be more easily debugged (e.g code that sets the `[data-color]` attribute).

Comment: Yeah the code is quite useful for debugging. I appreciate it a lot!